# How to determine demographics of users visiting your site?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Ad-Servers seem (and do) know a lot about the use who is visiting a certain webpage leveraging Behavioral and Contextual Targeting.  I would love to be able to keep track of that data as well.  In particular I would like to know:

- age range
- male/female
- geographical info

I would like this information on a per request basis (not a daily summary)

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are vendors who specialize in characterizing your Site's traffic. Very roughly they work by finding the closest match to your Site from among a large population of Sites in which they do in fact have detailed demographic data. To improve the matching, some of them give you a javascript snippet to insert into your Site's pages to collect user data and send it to their servers (more or less like web analytics code).

[Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/info/publisher-reports) is such vendor. The link i included will take you to their page that displays sample audience demographic reports.

[Crowd Science](http://www.crowdscience.com/) is another.

Neither of these are free (though they might have a *freemium* service, i don't know.

[Alexa](http://www.alexa.com), on the other hand, is free and offers similar data; just enter your Site's url in their textbox, then when you get the results page, select the *Audience* tab.

Answer (score 0):

Age and Gender: Ask your users.
Geographical Info: Use GeoIP targeting.

Comment: Thanks -- I would like to do this without asking visitors.  It is a content site (ie Blog) and I would like to know who my readers are without having them sign in

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Hitwise](http://www.hitwise.com/), but it's a little on the pricey side IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Doug's is a good answer, but Google Analytics now gives you this too, based on their acquisition of DoubleClick.  So it's free.

[Google Analytics Demographics & Interests](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en)

Note that no matter who you get this information from, the information is based on cross-site information.  This is based on "third party cookies" which many users turn off (sometimes without knowing they are doing this) depending on their browser's security/privacy settings.